# How to configure .htaccess to run JavaScript with node as CGI

Tags: python, node.js, apache2, cgi, javascript

I'm testing this on my linux localhost.

This is what I'm trying:

```
balter@spectre:/var/www/html$ cat .htaccess
Action cgi-node "/usr/bin/env node"
AddHandler cgi-node .js
balter@spectre:/var/www/html$ ls -al hello.js
-rwxr-xr-x 1 balter balter 99 Oct 31 13:17 hello.js
balter@spectre:/var/www/html$ cat hello.js
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log("Content-Type: text/html");
console.log("hello from javascript");
balter@spectre:/var/www/html$ node hello.js
Content-Type: text/html
hello from javascript
```

When I visit `localhost/hello.js` all I see is the contents of `hello.js`

**ADDITION**
I was wondering if I actually had cgi turned on. I figured I did because php worked. But I didn't have the cgi module enabled, or turned on in `apache.conf`.

So I added `cgi.load` and added to my `apache.conf`

```
###################################################################
#########     Adding capaility to run CGI-scripts #################
ServerName localhost
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py .js
```

Now, I get

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /hello.js on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Incidentally, same with an equivalent `hello.py`.

Comment: Testing your script with `node hello.js`  is incorrect, you will need to try and execute the script i.e. see what happens when you execute `/var/www/html/hello.js` or `./hello.js`- Also, for an administrator interpreting the generic error messages that are displayed in to a site visitor in their browser is frequently not nearly as useful as looking at the messages in the apache error log

Comment: Yeah, I talked to 1&1 and they won't let me see the apache error log :(. FWIW, the `ls -al` was to show that it is set to 755, and indeed does execute using the shebang.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked almost 2 years ago, but just in case someone else lands here looking for a way to write a very simple CGI using node:

The [Common Gateway Interface](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/howto/cgi.html#writing) requires a blank line between the headers and content.

The example script above can be fixed by adding a `\n` to the end of the `Content-Type` header:

```javascript
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log("Content-Type: text/html\n");
console.log("hello from javascript");
```

Or by adding an empty `console.log()` between the headers and content:

```javascript
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log("Content-Type: text/html");
console.log();
console.log("hello from javascript");
```

These are both functionally equivalent, so it’s really a matter of personal style.  #1 is microscopically more efficient, but not enough to recommend it if you find the explicitness of #2 easier to read.